# How can I set Linear Gradient using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm adding a header background image using javascript and css. I can add the image just find and it works, but I want to give the linear gradient using it but I'm not sure if my syntax is right or if it can even be done.

Below is the current working code that pulls the image followed by the code I have to try and get the gradient overlay as well. Is there something I'm missing on the "attempt" code? How can I get the gradient overlay to work properly?

**WORKING**

```
var url = headerImage;
var div = document.getElementById("propertyPageHeader");
div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`
```

**Attempt**

```
var url = headerImage;
var div = document.getElementById("propertyPageHeader");
div.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgba(57, 64, 70, 0.95), 
    rgba(57, 64, 70, 0.45)) center center / cover, url(${url})`
```

Comment: Did you mean backticks instead of single quotes? Right now `${url}` is passed literally to the style rule, and it probably doesn't parse as a valid URL, rendering the entire rule invalid.

Comment: yea, it copied weird....it works like I said without the linear gradient stuff, once I try adding the gradient it I can't get it to work

Comment: Your response to Thomas' question wasn't clear. Does your actual code have backticks or single quotes for the style string?

Comment: it had backticks for the working code, single quotes for the attempt

Answer (score 0):

After toying a little more, the following ultimately worked:

```
    var url = headerImage;
    var div = document.getElementById("propertyPageHeader");
    div.style.background ="linear-gradient(rgba(57, 64, 70, 0.95), rgba(57, 64, 70, 0.45)), url("+url+")";
```